# Laravel Socialite: InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php line 199:

Tags: facebook, laravel, authentication

For some reason I get this exception when I try to log in with Laravel Socialite with either Facebook or Google:

> InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php line 199:

The exception are thrown from my SocialiteController, when it tries to get the user from the facebook driver.

```
public function callback(SocialAccountService $service, $provider)
    {
        try {
            var_dump(Socialite::driver('facebook')->user());
```

Here are the part of AbstractProvider.php that seem to throw the actual exception:

```
public function user()
{
  if ($this->hasInvalidState()) {
     throw new InvalidStateException;
}
```

I have been following this tutorial https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-twitter-login.html#.WFK0BfnhCUk. The login have worked fine until last week, for some reason.

I read other articles saying I should change config/session.php so domain is not null but my current domain (in my case localhost:8000 since I run local with XAMPP), and refresh Laravel cache etc. But it did not work.

Comment: I ran into something similar when I was using a stateless api  ... check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/social-integration-without-using-the-session?page=1

Comment: Thanks. I have not looked in JWT yet, I am currently using the Laravel Sessions (stored as a file).

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that my Laravel application cookies where missing, which caused the InvalidStateException exception.

I also noticed that the cookies were not recreated after each HTTP request. When I changed the domain value in Config/Session.php from my current one ("localhost") to null (the default value), then the cookies were recreated again.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
session()->put('state', $request->input('state'));
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
```